# Typedef of a templated alias in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector, alias

I have a the following template class `A`:

```
template<template<typename>class VectorT>
class A
{
      //...
}
```

which I instantiate like this: `A<MyStdVector> objectA;` where `MyStdVector` is an alias for `std::vector` with a specific allocator (`MyAllocator`):

```
template<typename T>
using MyStdVector = std::vector<T,MyAllocator>
```

I decided to create an alias named `Vector` inside `A`:

```
template<template<typename>class VectorT>
class A
{
 public:
      template<typename T>
      using Vector = VectorT<T>;

      //...
}
```

such that inside `A` I can call `Vector<int>` (instead of `VectorT<int>`).
More important, I would like to access this alias `Vector` from another class `B`. **How to achieve this** :

```
template<class A>
class B
{
public:
    // How to define a type Vector which refers to A::Vector 
    // such that inside B, Vector<int> refers to A::Vector<int>
    // which refers to MyStdVector<int> 
}
```

in order to create an attribute `Vector<int>` in the class `B` for instance. 
So I have tried 3 things (inside class `B`):

```
typedef typename A::Vector Vector;   //1

template<typename T>
using Vector = typename A::Vector;   //2

template<typename T>
using Vector = typename A::Vector<T> //3
```

But the compiler says that the typename `A::Vector` names `StdVector` which is not a type (I guess it is only considered as an alias and not a type?) for the 2 first solutions. And the last solution produces a syntax error.

Here is the whole code I tried to compile :

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
using MyStdVector = std::vector<T/*,MyAllocator*/>;

template<template<typename>class VectorT>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    using Vector = VectorT<T>;

    //...
};

template<class A>
class B
{
public:
//    typedef typename A::Vector Vector;   // 1

//    template<typename T>
//    using Vector = typename A::Vector;   // 2

//    template<typename T>
//    using Vector = typename A::Vector<T>; // 3

    Vector<int> m_vector;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A<MyStdVector> a;
    B<A<MyStdVector>> b;
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused about the difference between `typedef` and `alias`, especially when I want to mix them and they are templated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type 3 adding a `template`

```
template <typename T>
using Vector = typename A::template Vector<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your confusion in the difference between `typedef` (C++98) and *alias declaration* (C++11): the difference lies in templates.

**alias declaration may be templatized while typedef cannot.**

Use `using` to declare myvector as a vector using a user-defined allocator:

```
template<typename T>
using myvector = std::vector<T, myAllocator<T>>  // alias declaration

myvector<int> myIntVector; // client code
```

To do the same thing with `typedef`, you have to nest typedef inside a struct template.

```
template<typename T>
struct myvector {
    typedef std::vector<T, myAllocator<T>> type;
}

myvector<int>::type myIntVector; // client code
```

The `::type` suffix is cumbersome, and you write fewer boilerplates with `using`. This is why you should prefer alias declaration to typedef.